# Ribbon XML dropdown control default selection

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm new to VSTO and I'm trying to create an Excel ribbon with some simple controls. I understand there are two ways to do this in Visual Studio. Ribbon XML and the Ribbon Designer, and from what I've read most people prefer the XML approach because it gives more flexibility.

I tried both approaches for creating a simple ribbon with a tab and a dropdown. With the Ribbon designer I get visible generated C# "code behind" that I can use to change the controls in runtime. Also, the dropdown is automatically defaulted to the first item, but with the generated C# objects I could set it to anything I want.

I try to do the same with the XML approach, and here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="myTab" label = "My Tab" >
        <group id="MyGroup" label="My Group" >
          <dropDown id="dropDown" label="Items">
            <item id="item1" label="Item 1" />
            <item id="item2" label="Item 2" />
            <item id="item3" label="Item 3" />
          </dropDown>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

But with this the combobox doesn't get a default item, it's just empty. And there is no visible "code behind" or data bindings that I can use? How do I set a default item for this control (e.g. id=item1).

Pictures for clarity

No default item:

[image: Not Initialized]

Has default item:

[image: Initialized]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any callbacks defined in your Ribbon XML will be executed automatically when the Ribbon loads (The only thing that needs to be initialized specifically is a reference to the Ribbon, itself). So if you want to specify the default using its ID include that callback in the dropdown definition. Alternatively, you can select by index.

The string assigned to `getSelectedItemID` (or `getSelectedItemIndex`) is the name of the procedure that should be executed.

Pay very close attention to the *method signatures* of ribbon call-backs. For C# `getSelectedItemId` needs to return a `string`; `getSelectedItemIndex` an `int`. You'll find a list of method signatures in Part 3 of the article series [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx/)

```
     // Ribbon1.xml
      <dropDown id ="dd1" getSelectedItemID="InitializeDropdown" >
        <item id="ddItem1" label="Item 1"/>
        <item id="ddItem2" label="Item 2"/>
      </dropDown>

    // Ribbon1.cs
    public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonX)
    {
        ribbon = ribbonX;
    }

    //will be executed automatically when Ribbon_Load runs
    public string InitializeDropdown(Office.IRibbonControl ctl)
    {
        return "ddItem2";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Cindy, it worked! I wish the vsto xml would work more like regular xaml when it comes to data binding.

Comment: Mmm, well, different origin, different team... The complexity is certainly a reason that the VSTO team invested resources into the Ribbon Designer. Important to keep in mind that the Ribbon XML was designed for Office, not Visual Studio, and that XML was pretty new over 10 years ago, when they were working on it. As I recall, XAML wasn't even in Visual Studio at the time!